# Access append query

Tags: ms-access, append

I have a table like below. It holds answers (QstnAnswer) to questions (QstnID) for different types of evalulations (EvalID) that happened during a patient encounter (EncounterID).

For each encounter where EvalID = 1, I need to append one record where the value of EncounterID is the same as the current encounter, EvalID = 1, QstnID = 9, and QstnAnswer is blank.

For example:

```
UniqueID (PK) EncounterID EvalID QstnID QstnAnswer
1             4           1      1      Yes
2             4           1      2      No
3             4           1      3      7.2
4             4           2      7      Open
5             4           2      8      Blue
6             231         1      1      Yes
7             231         1      2      Yes
8             231         1      3      5.1
```

There are two encounters (4 and 231) where EvalID = 1, so the append should add these two records:

```
UniqueID EncounterID EvalID QstnID QstnAnswer
9        4           1      9      
10       231         1      9
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What if QstnID = 9 already exists? Is UniqueID an AutoNumber field?

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I was able to solve this. I created 3 queries: 1) select query that returns a list of EncounterIDs and EvalsIDs (from two tables) along with QsntIDs (from a table holding only questions) which should apply to all evals. 2) make table query that links the results from the select query to the table of answers, where QstnID = Null. In the data above, this returns two records, one for each record where EvalID = 1 with the QstnID = 9 (because that was only question ID missing that should be there) 3) an append query that appends the results of the make table query to the table of responses.